# Handling null time in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am wanting to run a query like:

```
SELECT ...
JOIN ...
WHERE ...
AND upload.updated + interval 1 minute <= NOW()
```

The problem is that `upload.updated` can be `NULL` and if it is, the statement returns nothing. I want it so that if it is not null make the check if it is `<= NOW()`. Is that possible?

Comment: just to clarify, you do you not the nulls to appear in the output?

Comment: yes I do not!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the query to return rows where updated is NOT NULL and more than one minute old, but exclude rows where updated is NULL:

```
WHERE ...
 AND upload.updated IS NOT NULL 
 AND upload.updated + interval 1 minute <= NOW()
```

If you want the query to return rows where updated is more than one minute old, and also include rows where updated is NULL:

```
WHERE ...
 AND (upload.updated IS NULL 
  OR upload.updated + interval 1 minute <= NOW())
```